# How to draw surface with four space curves as boundaries

Tags: plotting, mesh

How to draw a surface with four space curves as boundaries of the surface?

```
ParametricPlot3D[{{u, 0, u^2}, {0, v, v^2}, {u, 1, u^2 + 1}, {1, v,1 + v^2}}, {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, 1}]
```

From this one:

[image]

to this one:

[image]

Your answer is appreciated.

Comment: These things are called 'Coons patches' - see here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coons_patch

Comment: Sometimes, this is also referred to as "transfinite interpolation".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As in my comment above, these are called 'Coons patches' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coons_patch

The following is simply adapted from the equations on that page:

```
c0[t_] := {t, 0, t^2}
d0[t_] := {0, t, t^2}
c1[t_] := {t, 1, 1 + t^2}
d1[t_] := {1, t, 1 + t^2}
lc[s_, t_] := (1 - t) c0[s] + t c1[s]
ld[s_, t_] := (1 - s) d0[t] + s d1[t]
b[s_, t_] := 
 c0[0] (1 - s) (1 - t) + c0[1] s (1 - t) + c1[0] (1 - s) t + c1[1] s t
patch[s_, t_] := lc[s, t] + ld[s, t] - b[s, t]
Show[
 ParametricPlot3D[#[t], {t, 0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
    PlotRange -> All, BoxRatios -> 1] & /@ {c0, d0, c1, d1},
 ParametricPlot3D[patch[s, t], {s, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> All,
   BoxRatios -> 1]
 ]
```

[image: coons patch plot]

Comment: I learned new things today. Thank you very much..^^